# Add checkbox AND radiobutton on license page

Tags: nsis

I'm writing scripts in Nsis and I need to have the option radio button on my license page **AND** a checkbox for another confirmation.
Is it possible to do so because if I try to insert both the higher priority is the checkbox and I'm missing radio buttons.
Preferable I would like to just modify the license page without creating a custom page!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Option A:

Use a modified (Resource Hacker) license page and apply it with ChangeUI (Or MUI_UI) and then use SendMessage to get the state at runtime.

### Option B:

Create a new checkbox at runtime with the system plugin:

```
!include nsdialogs.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_RADIOBUTTONS
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW licshow
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE licleave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Function licshow
System::Call '*(i,i,i,i)i.r1'
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $2 $0 0x40A
System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(ir2,ir1)'
System::Call 'USER32::MapWindowPoints(i0,ir0,ir1,i1)'
System::Call '*$1(i.r6,i.r7)'
System::Call 'USER32::GetClientRect(ir2,ir1)'
System::Call '*$1(i,i,i.r8,i.r9)'
IntOp $9 $9 + 3 ;padding
IntOp $7 $7 - $9
GetDlgItem $2 $0 0x3EE
System::Call 'USER32::GetClientRect(ir2,ir1)'
System::Call '*$1(i,i,i.r3,i.r4)'
System::Free $1
IntOp $4 $4 - $9 ;reduce size of label
System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(ir2,i,i,i,ir3,ir4,i6)'
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Some option",i ${__NSD_CheckBox_STYLE},ir6,ir7,ir8,ir9,ir0,i666,i0,i0)i.r2'
SendMessage $0 ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $0
SendMessage $2 ${WM_SETFONT} $0 1
${NSD_SetState} $2 1 ;check it
FunctionEnd

Function licleave
FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $0 $0 666
${NSD_GetState} $0 $1
MessageBox mb_ok "Checkbox=$1"
FunctionEnd
```

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is great way to do this. Absolutely the easiest. But the syntax is a total mess. Can you show how to add another checkbox above/below the one you already added?

Comment: @wpfwannabe: Yes it is hard to code that way so at some point you should start thinking about using a custom page...

Comment: So you do not think adding another checkbox is easy or even possible? How would I go about using a custom page? I really want the built-in functionality with just two checkboxes. Please feel free to post answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670969/two-checkboxes-on-a-nsis-license-page).