# Two checkboxes on a NSIS license page

Tags: nsis

I am trying to do pretty much what is being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037312/add-checkbox-and-radiobutton-on-license-page) but due to the complexity of the syntax and shortage of time, I need someone to help me out on this.

I have spent a couple of hours try to get TWO checkboxes shown instead of one but I keep failing. The NSIS syntax is killing me and I can't seem to get the params to the second `USER32::CreateWindowEx` right. I want to display the second checkbox below (or to the right) of the first one.

So far I have done the following modifications but this doesn't seem to create the second checkbox (please see the original post for the rest of the code).

```
; ---<snip>---
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Some option",i ${__NSD_CheckBox_STYLE},ir6,ir7,ir8,ir9,ir0,i666,i0,i0)i.r2'
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Second option",i ${__NSD_CheckBox_STYLE},ir6+100,ir7,ir8,ir9,ir0,i667,i0,i0)i.r3'
SendMessage $0 ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $0
SendMessage $2 ${WM_SETFONT} $0 1
SendMessage $3 ${WM_SETFONT} $0 1
${NSD_SetState} $2 1 ;check it
${NSD_SetState} $3 1 ;check it
FunctionEnd

Function licleave
FindWindow $5 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $0 $5 666
GetDlgItem $1 $5 667
${NSD_GetState} $0 $0
${NSD_GetState} $1 $1
MessageBox mb_ok "Checkbox=$0 $1"
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do math like `ir6+100` in a system::call (You can only OR simple numbers), try `IntOp $6 $6 + 100` before you create the second checkbox.

Edit:

The code from the other answer also gave the checkbox the same width as the dialog so any other control added to the right of it will appear behind it.

You must adjust the size of the first checkbox as well:

```
...
IntOp $8 $8 / 2 ; Use half the width
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Some option",i ${__NSD_CheckBox_STYLE},ir6,ir7,ir8,ir9,ir0,i666,i0,i0)i.r2'
IntOp $6 $6 + $8 ; Offset 2nd checkbox by the width of the first
System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "Button",t "Other option",i ${__NSD_CheckBox_STYLE},ir6,ir7,ir8,ir9,ir0,i667,i0,i0)i.r3'
...
```

Comment: Tried that too. Didn't seem to have effect. I see just the first checkbox.

Comment: @wpfwannabe: You might have to reduce the width of the first checkbox

Comment: That's it. Thanks! I was looking for a vertical layout but this might just do the trick.